# Set static IP in OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server (pivpn.io), and three server clients.

I'm trying to set a static IP address, for the VPN clients.

I've created `ipp.txt` `/etc/openvpn/ccd/ipp.txt`.

The file `ipp.txt` uses the following syntax:

[client name],[ip address]
`miami-test,10.8.0.5`

When connecting the server is not issuing a static ip address.

Answer (score 5):

That's because that is not how you manually assign IP addresses. There is a file `ipp.txt` that OpenVPN can maintain, so that clients (sometimes) get the same IP address reassigned to them if they reconnect or OpenVPN restarts.

See the sample config:

```
# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
```

But that's not what you've configured.

The files in the `ccd` directory are interpreted as client-specific configuration. So creating a file `ccd/ipp.txt` causes OpenVPN to attempt to interpret the file's contents as directives applying to a client named `ipp.txt`.

This doesn't appear to be what you want.

Let's go back to the sample config:

```
# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2
```

So it looks like you want a file named `ccd/miami-test` containing `ifconfig-push 10.8.0.5 10.8.0.6`.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`:

`ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt`

`client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd`

I renamed `/etc/openvpn/ccd/miami-test.user` to `/etc/openvpn/ccd/miami-test`

I rebooted the Miami server, and used `pivpn -c` which displays a list of the clients, and Miami-test is now using `10.8.0.8` (the static ip address i assigned it).

Thanks, for the Help!